# Hypothesis test based on (random) result of previous experiment: can I multiply confidence levels?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, bernoulli-distribution, sequential-analysis

Consider an i.i.d. sequence of Bernoulli random variables $\{Z_i\}$ with Bernoulli parameter $x$. By a certain procedure (experiment A) I obtain a random set *S* such that $\mathrm{Pr}[x \in S] \geq c_A$, where $c_\mathrm A$ is a prescribed confidence value. That random set is always of the form $S = S_1 \cup S_2$, where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are disjoint intervals. What I mean by $S$ being random is that those intervals' endpoints are random numbers determined by the observed sequence $\{Z_i\}$.

For each realization of $S$, I conduct an hypothesis test (experiment B) to decide whether $x$ is in $S_1$ or in $S_2$, where $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the random intervals resulting from each realization of experiment A. For this test I use samples $\{Z_j\}$ statistically independent of those used in experiment A. Let $d \in \{1,2\}$ denote the decision produced by the test ($d=1$ means "$x \in S_1$", and similarly for $d=2$). Experiment B is designed so that the decision $d$ is correct (i.e. $x$ actually belongs to $S_d$) with probability at least $c_\mathrm B$, which is again a prescribed confidence value.

More specifically, experiment B consists in observing a number $N$ of variables $Z_j$, computing a statistic $t$ from them, and defining a threshold $t_0$ such that $d$ is declared to be $1$ if $t \geq t_0$, and otherwise $d$ is declared to be $2$. *Both $N$ and $t_0$ depend on the (random) sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ obtained from experiment A*.

I would like to be able to say that $\mathrm{Pr}[x \in S_d] = \Pr[x \in S_d | x \in S] \cdot \mathrm{Pr}[x \in S]$. That would imply that $\mathrm{Pr}[x \in S_d] \geq c_\mathrm A \cdot c_\mathrm B$. I would thus obtain a confidence interval for $x$ (namely, $S_d$) with associated confidence level $c_\mathrm A \cdot c_\mathrm B$.

Is the reasoning in the previous paragraph correct? My concern stems from the fact that the *design* of the hypothesis test is based on the observed $S_1$ and $S_2$. That could be introducing some kind of dependence or other effect that invalidates my reasoning. Or, put it another way, the hypothesis test is *random* (not just the result, but the *design* of the test itself), and  is determined by the outcome of experiment A. I don't know how I should deal with that.